# CMD check tools & inconsistent results

Tags: r, cmd, continuous-integration, devtools, cran

The R community has provided several tools to check if packages install properly under different operating systems (e.g. Rhub, CI via travis /github actions, local CMD checks, devtools::check_win_devel()).

Occasionally, I experience that I pass one set of tests but not another. Why might this be the case, and is there something one can learn from a passed cmd check (e.g. via github actions) and a failed test (e.g. via rhub)?

Comment: if you are [submitting to cran](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html), i don't see how the others have any relevance at all, but I can also see this as being flagged/closed as opinion

Comment: Thanks for your feedback - I have rephrased my question and hope that it is now less likely to  evoke open-ended exchanges of opinions and preferences.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of an open-ended question, and subject to opinion.  But my 2 cents is that the local cmd checks with CRAN flag are essential and checking on at least one machine besides your development environment is highly desirable, and will reduce the number of iterations with CRAN.  The outside machine can be either RHub, Travis, GitHub Actions, or something else.  Even another machine you own.  The reason this is valuable is because there can be hidden dependencies in your development environment that don't become apparent until you move the package to another machine.  In the end, none of the pre-testing techniques will be as good as the CRAN checks.  So you can pass everything, and still fail the CRAN checks.  You can also fail the CRAN checks on one OS, and pass all the others.  You can also pass the CRAN checks on one day, then they change the checks, so next time you fail with the same code.  In the end you just check as thoroughly as you can and then iterate with them until it is approved.